# In creating a primary key in a Forerunner database collection, can the key property live inside of an object of the collection object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, forerunnerdb

I have a work-around, however I'm wondering why this is failing - is it a JavaScript error on my part?
My app uses two models. I'm using Forerunner to persist a JSON model that is previously created in my MVC.
I want to store the Forerunner primary key in an object, to make it clearer (in my first model) that the key is used only in the Forerunner model. 
The key will need to be saved in both models, so that when the first model changes, I can immediately update the Forerunner model - it is the link between two models.

Here is a code sample to illustrate:

```
var games = db.collection("games", {
    primaryKey: "gamedb._id"
});

games.insert({
    gamedb : {
        _id: 1,
    },
    userDesc : "original 11x11",
    Size : [11,11],
    Plays : []
    .
    .
}, function (result) {
       console.log(result);
});
```

I did try it out, and got confusing results, so for now I'm just leaving the key as property of the collection.
Here is the console.log result of my attempt using the above code sample. The forerunner insert() did not fail.
I'm confused about the  property 'gamedb._id : "225b...".
Thanks for any suggestions or insight.

```
    gamedb : Object
    _id: 1
    gamedb._id: "225b3c25aeb38a0",
}
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys in ForerunnerDB must currently be in the root of the object. When you tell it to make the primary key "gamedb._id" it is not parsing that string as a path, it is assuming you are passing that as a root key e.g. {"gamedb._id": myId}

There are plans to update ForerunnerDB to allow nested primary keys, but this is not currently possible.

Source: I wrote ForerunnerDB